# How to convert JSON to array of strings

Tags: sql, arrays, json, sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to use `for json path` to format rows in a JSON array format?

I have a column like this

```
Col1
====
abc
def
ghi
jkl
```

and I want to format it like this

```
{"Col1":["abc","def","ghi","jkl"]}
```

I have so far gotten it to look like this

```
{["Col1":"abc","Col1":"def","Col1":"ghi","Col1":"jkl"]}
```

using this code

```
select col1 from table for json path
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a bit of string manipulation.

Creating a simple array seems like a missed opportunity.

```
Select Col1 = json_query('["'+string_agg(string_escape(Col1,'json'), '","') +'"]')
 From  YourTable
  For  json path, Without_Array_Wrapper
```

**Results**

```
{"Col1":["abc","def","ghi","jkl"]}
```

If your version is <2017, `string_agg()` would not be available.  However, you can use the `stuff()/xml` approach

```
Select Col1 = json_query('["'+stuff((Select concat('","',string_escape(Col1,'json'))  
                                      From  YourTable 
                                      For XML Path ('')),1,3,'')+'"]')
   For  json path, Without_Array_Wrapper
```

Comment: I won't lie, it feels like there should be a less clunky method, but I can't think of one.

Comment: SQL Server 2022 is promising to enhance JSON API functionality.

Comment: Sad Guess I just have to jank my way through it lol!

Comment: `For XML Path (''), TYPE).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)')` would be wise, to avoid XML escaping

Comment: @Larnu Two things that are really badly missing about SQL Server's JSON functionality: `JSON_AGG` as here, and `JSON_OBJECT_AGG` for property/value pairs