# How to create a single JSON array from two SELECT statements using SQL Server JSON functionality?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have the following SQL Statement:

```
SELECT
    (
        SELECT TOP 1
            Site.Reference,
            (
                SELECT TOP 1 ProjectId FROM Project WHERE Project.Siteid = Site.SiteId ORDER BY ProjectId ASC
            ) AS FirstId,
            (
                SELECT TOP 1 ProjectId FROM Project WHERE Project.Siteid = Site.SiteId ORDER BY ProjectId DESC
            ) AS LastId
        FROM 
            Site
        WHERE
            (Site.SiteId = 348)
        FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('seriesdata')
) AS JSONData
```

`Site` is the parent and `Project` is the child in a one-to-many relationship.

The output from this Query is:

```
JSONData
{"seriesdata":[{"Reference":"SIT0003237","FirstId":216,"LastId":1263}]}
```

The output I require is :

```
JSONData
{"seriesdata":[{"Reference":"SIT0003237","IdRange":[216,1263]}]}
```

I am failing to find how to implement this in SQL Server with the use of the JSON functionality. I would be grateful for any help to find a solution.

Comment: You can't create a simple array in SQL Server (missed opportunity).   This would require a little string manipulation   Take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70511213/how-to-convert-json-to-array-of-strings/70511399#70511399

Comment: In SQL 2022 you can finally generate arrays! https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql-blog/announcing-json-enhancements-in-azure-sql-database-azure-sql/ba-p/3417071

Comment: Generating arrays - about time! A native solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just join two tables and do the grouping by Reference, take the MIN and MAX from the Project Id, concatenate and wrap it in [JSON_QUERY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

```
SELECT (
  SELECT
    Site.Reference,
    JSON_QUERY('[' + CAST(MIN(ProjectId) AS VARCHAR) + ',' + CAST(MAX(ProjectId) AS VARCHAR) + ']') AS IdRange
    FROM Site
    JOIN Project ON Project.Siteid = Site.SiteId
    WHERE Site.SiteId = 348
    GROUP BY Site.Reference
    FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('seriesdata')
) AS JSONData
```

In the context of your question, the essence does not change - you need to concatenate two numbers into a json array as a string and wrap it in JSON_QUERY

```
SELECT (
  SELECT TOP 1
      Site.Reference,
      JSON_QUERY('[' + 
        (SELECT TOP 1 CAST(ProjectId AS VARCHAR) FROM Project WHERE Project.Siteid = Site.SiteId ORDER BY ProjectId ASC) +
        ','+
        (SELECT TOP 1 CAST(ProjectId AS VARCHAR) FROM Project WHERE Project.Siteid = Site.SiteId ORDER BY ProjectId DESC) +
      ']') AS IdRange
  FROM Site
  WHERE Site.SiteId = 348
  FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('seriesdata')
) AS JSONData
```

See [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/G8Ig40FK)